# Does ADO Recordset need to be closed?

Tags: vbscript, ado

I have an ADO recordset (not ADO.NET) that I populate in every iteration of a loop. 
My question is: Do I need to close the recordset at end of every iteration so it gets populated with fresh data in next iteration OR I could just use the unclosed recordset to populate with new data in next iteration. Please look at code sample below.

```
set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

for count = 0 to 3

  rs.Open "Select * from Customers where CustomerId = " & count, conn

  'do some processing of data in recordset

  'rs.Close 'NOT VERY SURE IF I NEED TO DO THIS

next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot open a recordset again :

```
Error 3705 : Operation is not allowed when the object is open
```

So given the sample above which requires a different selection of data, you must close the recordset.